# Spring amqp throwing Listener not registered when publish confirm is enabled on second call

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, spring-integration-amqp

i have been trying to get a Spring RabbitMQ publisher with publisher confirms turned on . The first calls goes through fine and confirm callback is returned. from second call onwards it fails with following error message

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Listener not registered: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate@42802df2 []
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Listener not registered: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate@42802df2 []
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Listener not registered: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate@42802df2 []
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSendAndReceiveWithDirect(RabbitTemplate.java:1650)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSendAndReceive(RabbitTemplate.java:1531)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive(RabbitTemplate.java:1320)
    at com.example.messagequeueintegration.impl.RabbitMQFacade.sendMessage(RabbitMQFacade.java:83)
    at com.example.messagequeueintegration.impl.RabbitMQFacade.sendMessage(RabbitMQFacade.java:68)
    at com.example.messagequeueintegration.impl.RabbitMQFacade.sendPaymentMessage(RabbitMQFacade.java:51)
    at com.example.messagequeueintegration.server.rest.controllers.SendMessageController.sendPaymentMessage(SendMessageController.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Listener not registered: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate@42802df2 []
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.addPendingConfirm(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:937)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:981)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.addPendingConfirm(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.setupConfirm(RabbitTemplate.java:2007)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1979)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.exchangeMessages(RabbitTemplate.java:1732)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSendAndReceiveAsListener(RabbitTemplate.java:1683)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSendAndReceiveWithDirect(RabbitTemplate.java:1645)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

This is how my configuration looks like

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(
                env.getRequiredProperty(QUEUE_HOST),
                env.getRequiredProperty(QUEUE_PORT, Integer.class));
        cachingConnectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }



    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }


    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageUtil messageUtil(
            @Qualifier("messagequeueintegration") ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new MessageUtil(objectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public BrokerFacade brokerFacade(
            @Qualifier("messagequeueintegration") ObjectMapper objectMapper,
            Environment environment,
            MessageUtil messageUtil) {
        return new RabbitMQFacade(objectMapper, environment, messageUtil);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange topicExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(TOPIC_EXCHANGE_KEY);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding queue2Binding(@Qualifier("queue2") Queue queue2, TopicExchange topicExchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue2).to(topicExchange)
                .with(env.getRequiredProperty("queue2name"));
    }

    @Bean
    Binding queue1Binding(@Qualifier("queue1") Queue queue1, TopicExchange topicExchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queueq).to(topicExchange)
                .with(env.getRequiredProperty("queue1name"));
    }


    @Bean
    public Queue queue1() {

        return new Queue(
                env.getRequiredProperty("queue1name"),
                true,
                false,
                true;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue2() {
        return new Queue(
                env.getRequiredProperty("queue2name"),
               true,
                false,
               true);
    }
```

i autowire the rabbittemplate and call it with publisher confirm call backs like given below

```
Message amqpMessage = new Message(message.getBytes(), new MessageProperties());
        rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback((cdata, ack, cause) -> {
            System.out.println("Confirm callback"+ ack +" for "+cdata.toString());
        });
        rabbitTemplate.setReturnCallback((msg,replyCode,replyText,
                exchange,  routingKey)->{
            System.out.println("call back returned for "+ routingKey);
        });
        rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
        rabbitTemplate
                .sendAndReceive(TOPIC_EXCHANGE_KEY,environment.getProperty(correlationData.getMessageType().getQueueName()),
                        amqpMessage, createCorrelationData(correlationData));
```

After a lot of debugging i found out that it is failing because the template is not getting registered as a listener in the new instances of `PublisherCallbackChannelImpl` which are created by the subsequent calls after the first one . I am kind of lost as to whether this is a configuration issue or an issue with publisher confirm logic . Any insights to this will be really helpful. Thanks

Edit 
I am using spring-amqp version 2.0.3-RELEASE and spring-messaging version 5.0.6-RELEASE

Edit2 : Debug logs for first and second calls 
https://gist.github.com/jissjanardhanan/cbad51ba77fad3eda484d7c33c0b1517

Comment: What version are you using? That stack trace looks incomplete; there should be a cause for the `UncategorizedAmqpException`; can you enable DEBUG logging and post the log someplace that shows the first and second send? It shouldn't affect things, but you really shouldn't set new callbacks for each request.

Comment: edited my question to include more complete logs and versions. i will enable debug logs and will try to post it . i had callbacks defined at the bean creation time of rabbit template, as you correctly guessed made no difference

Comment: Sounds like we remove listener from the channel, but don't remove cache entry from the `publisherConfirmChannels`. I wonder if we need such a cache at all there...

Comment: Uh! Missed somehow. Any chances to give us some simple project to play with? Looks like code has not been changed in that area... We need something to reproduce and confirm the issue. Sorry for delay and thank you for understanding!

Comment: Let me see if i can put something up in github. Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 0):

```
rabbitTemplate.setUseDirectReplyToContainer(false);
```

@see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/846#issuecomment-439072434

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: This is a bug in GitHub